# Adding paypal and "add to cart" to my wamp server

Tags: php, paypal

I have added the ability to register on my site using wamp (phpMyAdmin). I would like to know if anyone could give me adice on how to link papal to the account and also have a cart that goes along with it. Are their any suggestions on how to do this? I have accounts set up but i am not sure how to make it so that someone can use their accounts to have a cart ad paypal.

Comment: what about starting to design a proper database design on how you store the data on your ecommerce site and then looking at the paypal docs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to implement a PayPal payment system in your website but we're not able to tell you how, because it is way to complex and would fill a book. Best solution is to check out by yourself and if you get problems, ask specific questions.

http://developer.paypal.com

You could also use magento - a commercial online shop software - as it is a very good shop system. It comes with a integrated PayPal checkout.

www.magento.com